# colorbox window size justify

Tags: colorbox

I am trying to call colorbox with the following js:

```
$.colorbox({html: '<img src="example.com/some.jpg">some more html tags..',});
```

img is dynamically generated. the problem is that colorbox opens but with very tiny window. How to make colorbox justify the window automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what size the image will be?  If so, you could solve it by putting the dimensions on the `<img>` element:

```
<img src='example.jpg' width='500' height='500'/>
```

Comment: thanks. that worked and I also had to set `innerWidth` and `innerHeight` based on the image size - had to add some extra fixed height to `innerHeight` due to html below the image, fortunately this extra html is always the same in my case.